# getPageSource is not locating item-Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop

I am trying to write a code where an user has typed in Python, hit enter and this app "Python tutorial Tutorials Point" is on the 4th page. My logic is: locate this item using getPageSource and keep on clicking on Next button. However 2 problems I see:
1)Pages found 0- I am expecting a lot more pages and the xpath shows 56+
2) It keeps on clicking on next button and goes to page 6 meaning it did not find that book on page 4.

```
public class AmazonProductSearchTest {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("Python");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Go']")).click();

        //Implicit wait till page loads
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Scroll down to find pagination
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,5000)", "");
        //Number of Pages
        List<WebElement> pagesFound=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/s?k=python')]"));
        System.out.println("Pages found "+ pagesFound.size());

        //Will click on Next link until we find a specific book-using page source
        while(!driver.getPageSource().equals("Python tutorial Tutorials Point")){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
            if(driver.getPageSource().equals("Python tutorial Tutorials Point")){
                System.out.println("Found searched item");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I could use some hint/help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: (!driver.getPageSource().equals("Python tutorial Tutorials Point")) should be (!driver.getPageSource().contains("Python tutorial Tutorials Point"))

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Comment: You good with grabbing the text of the second-to-last li within the a-pagination class to get the number of pages?

Answer (score 0):

pagesFound is referring to Next button (//a[contains(@href, '/s?k=python')]). I believe the pagesFound should use the last disabled number which refer to actual number of pagesFound and not the Next button. Copy pasted above code and the list was empty.

Comment: While I agree with you this is a cleaner way to get the number of pages, especially since most of them are in the ... part, the first issue was that s?k=python should be s?k=Python with an upper case P (I think xPath is case sensitiove)

Comment: It was case sensitive, once I changed it to P(instead of p), I got 76 pages.